# Remove + (plus symbol) from url using .htaccess or PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've recently made some changes to my website's .htaccess file. I have a search form that searches a database using a simple php script.

Right now if a user searches for "red trucks" from mysite.com/search.php my website returns mysite.com/red+trucks.php (I've already set the .htaccess file to create friendly urls and to 301 redirect). I'm wondering how I remove the +plus symbols and change them to - hyphens?

My .htaccess file looks like this with your change put in CMate

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)\.php search.php?pro_query=$1
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)\.php$ /scripts/search.php?pro_query=$1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pro_query=([0-9,a-z,.*,%25,%2B,%+]+)$
RewriteRule ^scripts/search\.php /search/%1.php? [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^+]*)\+(.*) $1\-$2 [N]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule if it is fine to replace all `+` symbols to `-`:

```
RewriteRule ^([^+]*)\+(.*) $1\-$2 [N]
```

In your case add it as the last rule.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately it didn't work. I received a "No Data Sent". The page is dynamically created and if a user types in more then one word the page produced includes a + between both words.

Comment: A version of my htaccess is pasted below :

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)\.php search.php?pro_query=$1
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)\.php$ /scripts/search.php?pro_query=$1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pro_query=([0-9,a-z,.*,%25,%2B,%+]+)$
RewriteRule ^scripts/search\.php /search/%1.php? [R=301,NC,L]

Comment: I guess the error is not in the above rule, as it really only replaces `+` symbols to `-` in an iterative way. Please show how you combined it with your existing htaccess file.

Comment: You may use some 3rdparty site to paste code, like http://pastebin.com/, it is hardly readable in a comment.

Comment: Ok, I'll add it to the question, I can't get new lines to work in the comments here.

Comment: You should make it the last rule, to execute after the query string has been placed as the file name.

Comment: I must have something wrong with my search.php script. After updating the .htaccess file with what you had it reverts two or more worded searches to something like this...  mysite.com/scripts/search.php?pro_query=phone+repair when searching for phone repair. I also reference the users query on the page as a <h2> item, which has the url the way I want it in the address bar. I'm thinking that something is backwards with the way I'm pulling (GET) data? For instance when the user types red truck a +plus symbol is put in as a spacer?

Comment: I added it at the bottom and it's still not working. Maybe the previous .htaccess lines are affecting how the query string and the url are matched? I noticed that the (+plus) symbols did change to hyphens on the page as content, but in the url bar the links have reverted to how they we're before I did the original .htaccess change to make the urls more friendly. The site is findrochestermn.com/search.php